# Is it possible to login as a page using Google+ Login

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to use Google+ login page to allow users to login as pages to the site?

Otherwise, is there an API to get information about a logged in user pages? Or do I need to request access to [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup)?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in

Comment: I believe it is possible, but not all users have access to the function because you need to set a page password.  I'm looking for a source on this though.  (From experience, though, the account needs to be above 18 years old for one to set a password, which is a weird restriction but it is the case)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this is possible.  However, the user would need to [register a password](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4570250?hl=en) on their page, which, according to the [help topic](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4570250?hl=en), "is currently not available to pages owned by Google Apps accounts or users under the age of 18".  I don't believe most people have this set up.  You could request having such people set this up, but if they fall under that group they would be out of luck.
As such, I would recommend that you look for another way of doing this.